# How to stop animation in jQuery after one rotation done?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want animation stop animation when text `Reacting` is appear, and after stop animation `Reacting` text will be stay there.

```js
// TextScramble


class TextScramble {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el
    this.chars = '!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________'
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ''
      const to = newText[i] || ''
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({ from, to, start, end })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ''
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
}

// Example


const phrases = [
  'Judgement',
  'Reacting'
]

const el = document.querySelector('.text')
const fx = new TextScramble(el)

let counter = 0
const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
    setTimeout(next, 800)
  })
  counter = 3 % phrases.length
}

next()
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100';
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  background: #212121;
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
.text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fafafa;
}
.dud {
  color: #757575;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
const next = () => {
  if ((counter) < phrases.length) {
    fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
      setTimeout(next, 800)
    })
    counter++;
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
// TextScramble


class TextScramble {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el
    this.chars = '!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________'
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ''
      const to = newText[i] || ''
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({
        from,
        to,
        start,
        end
      })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ''
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let {
        from,
        to,
        start,
        end,
        char
      } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
}

// Example


const phrases = [
  'Judgement',
  'Reacting'
]

const el = document.querySelector('.text')
const fx = new TextScramble(el)

let counter = 0
const next = () => {
  if ((counter) < phrases.length) {
    fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
      setTimeout(next, 800)
    })
    counter++;
  }
}

next()
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono:100';
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  background: #212121;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.dud {
  color: #757575;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```